# How can I detect a mongo database change via spring AbstractMongoEventListener

Tags: spring, mongodb, event-listener

I need an application that listens to the changes in mongodb and send a response to user. The changes are done to the database by external post requests, then I need an event listener firing up.

I searched for days and I got the idea that this can be achieved through `AbstractMongoEventListener` class.

I connected to my local mongodb instance using `spring.data.mongodb.host, spring.data.mongodb.port, spring.data.mongodb.database`. And I can save data from my spring back-end and retrieve them on port 8080.

Now I used postman to store data in the mongodb instance using external post requests. I need to detect these changes to the database from my back-end.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297262/how-do-i-register-abstractmongoeventlistener-programmatically) I got some idea, but it doesn't really explains how to register the `AbstractMongoEventListener`'s `onAfterSave` method.

Here is my event listener,

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AbstractMongoEventListener;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterSaveEvent;

public class HotelsRepositoryListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {

    @Override
    public void onAfterSave(AfterSaveEvent<Object> event) {
        super.onAfterSave(event);
        System.out.println("Saved");
    }
}
```

I think I must implement a configuration class to register this listener but I have no idea how to do it. Here is my`pom.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot with mongodb</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've seen that we can use `Bean` and some annotations to register this. But I don't have a clear idea on it. Can someone help me how to figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AbstractMongoEventListener` class implements interface `ApplicationListener` which is part of spring context module(spring has eventing mechanism from box, you can add your own listeners for different actions without direct connection of components. For more details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events), that means you can register your listener through annotating `HotelsRepositoryListener` with `@Component` and add package with that listener for scanning(`@ComponentScan` annotation) or create configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public HotelsRepositoryListener hotelsRepositoryListener() {
        return new HotelsRepositoryListener();
    }

}
```